# Run RStudio on Amazon AWS Ec2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I am connected with an AWS Ec2 instance.

Last time I used this service one year ago. Normally a window in my taskbar pops up with a second screen of my desktop where I can run RStudio in the cloud.  However, this time nothing happened.

I use:

- Windows 10 (64 bit)
- R version 3.5.2 (64 bit)

How can I run RStuion on AWS?

Comment: are you using an AMI, e.g. http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/?

Comment: what is the OS of this instance?

Comment: I use `RStudio-1.1.456_R-3.5.1_CUDA-9.0_cuDNN-7.2.1_ubuntu-16.04-LTS-64bit - ami-0cccb5af1db2d3ec6`

Comment: @BigDataScientist I am now using the AMI interface from Louis Aslett which seems to work, thanks.